# Clear a specific context of a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm working on a project with HTML canvas and I'm in trouble with a few things.

I want to be able to clear a specific context of my canvas without altering others. 
Here is an example :

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('dessin');
var context1 = canvas.getContext('2d');
var context2 = canvas.getContext('2d');

context1.beginPath();
context1.arc(100, 100, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
context1.fill();
context1.closePath();

context2.beginPath();
context2.fillStyle = 'red';
context2.arc(200, 200, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
context2.fill();
context2.closePath();


document.getElementById('clearCanvas1').onclick = function(){
   context1.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/amwnhx0m/

I've got 2 contexts on the same canvas : context1 which draws a black circle and context2 which draws a red circle.

When I put a clearRect on context1 it is appended on the whole canvas so the context2 disappears. I wonder if it's possible to keep context2 without redrawing after the clearRect (performance issue)

Comment: Reading through the standards https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#dom-canvas-getcontext a canvas can only point to one context at a time. It is unclear how but it is likely that `context1`, and `context2` both referance the same object

Comment: Yes, a canvas has only 1 context and all references to `canvas.getContext('2d')` refer to the same context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## 1. Single Canvas

As `Blindman67` mentioned in his comment, the standard says that a canvas can only point to one context. In your situation, `context1` has the same value as `context2`. Declaring `context2` doesn't give you a sort of *"new layer"*. Your code really should just use one context like this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("design");
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

As for drawing your circles, use the `context` variable instead.

```
context.beginPath();
context.arc(100, 100, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
context.fill();
context.closePath();

context.beginPath();
context.fillStyle = 'red';
context.arc(200, 200, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
context.fill();
context.closePath();
```

So answering your question, one way you can specifically clear out a portion of the canvas is by calling `clearRect` only around the area of the black circle.

```
context.clearRect(50, 50, 100, 100);
```

This only clears a certain portion of the canvas.

## 2. Multiple Canvases

One way you can draw two things on different contexts is by using multiple canvases stacked on top of one another. Use the `z-index` in CSS to position which canvas you want on top.

```
<style>
    .canvasHolder{
        position: relative;
        height: 500px; width: 500px; //based on your canvas size
    }
    .canvas{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0; left: 0;
    }
</style>

<div class="canvasHolder">
    <canvas class="canvas" id="dessin1" width="500" height="500"> ... </canvas>
    <canvas class="canvas" id="dessin2" width="500" height="500"> ... </canvas>
</div>

<button id="clearCanvas1"> Clear canvas1 (black circle) </button>
```

In Javascript, you should declare two separate canvases and contexts for each. This way, you can treat them as separate layers.

```
var canvas1 = document.getElementById('dessin1');
var context1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');

var canvas2 = document.getElementById('dessin2');
var context2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');

context1.beginPath();
context1.arc(100, 100, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
context1.fill();
context1.closePath();

context2.beginPath();
context2.fillStyle = 'red';
context2.arc(200, 200, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
context2.fill();
context2.closePath();


document.getElementById('clearCanvas1').onclick = function(){
    context1.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
};
```

Hope it helps.